# Why can't I resolve the error ' WelcomeController # index is missing a template for this request format and variant. '?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My ruby ​​version is 3.0.0, my mysql version is 5.7, my mysql2 version is 0.5.3,
my bundler version is 2.2.3, my rails version is 5.0.7.2,
and my Xcode version is 12.5.
I use macOS Big Sur(version 11.2.2.) and Atom of the text editor.

I'm under production of the application called 'food-board'.

When I executed the command `rails s`, I got the following error code in the terminal.

```
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 35ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



ActionController::UnknownFormat (WelcomeController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["text/html"]
request.variant: []):
```

The above error code says "There is no template in the #index method of WelcomeController",

so I executed the following command to add routes, controllers, and views.

```
$ rails g controller Welcome index --no-helper --no-assets
      
      create  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb
       route  get 'welcome/index'
      invoke  erb
      create    app/views/welcome
      create    app/views/welcome/index.html.erb
```

The following two files(`app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb`、
`app/views/welcome/index.html.erb`) was added to the food-board folder after executing the command `$ rails g controller Welcome index --no-helper --no-assets` .

```
food-board
  └app
    └controllers
      └concerns
      └application_controller.rb
      └welcome_controller.rb
    └views
      └layouts
      └welcome
        └index.html.erb
  └config
    └routes.rb
```

The following code has been added to the file `app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb` after executing the command `$ rails g controller Welcome index --no-helper --no-assets`.

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

The following code has been added to the file `config/route.rb` after executing the command `$ rails g controller Welcome index --no-helper --no-assets`.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

The following code has been added to the file `app/views/welcome/index.html.erb` after executing the command `$ rails g controller Welcome index --no-helper --no-assets`.

```
<h1>Welcome#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/welcome/index.html.erb</p>
```

After executing the command `$ rails g controller Welcome index --no-helper --no-assets`,
I edited the file`config/route.rb` as follows.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "welcome#index"
  get "welcome/index"
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

The result of the execution of the command `rails routes` is as follows.

```
$ rails routes
       
       Prefix Verb URI Pattern              Controller#Action
         root GET  /                        welcome#index
welcome_index GET  /welcome/index(.:format) welcome#index
```

When I executed the command `rails s` again、 I got the following error code in the terminal.

```
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 35ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



ActionController::UnknownFormat (WelcomeController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["text/html"]
request.variant: []):
```

Would I like you to tell me why I can't resolve the following error?

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat (WelcomeController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `Ruby 3.0.0` does not support this version of rails. So you should install `ruby 2.7.3` and then try as I check all other code there is no issue in them, it is only your ruby version.

Please make sure you check your `Gemfile` it may have mentioned about your ruby version and also if any `.ruby_versin` file in your root that may have ruby version.

When you go in your root folder make sure you are running `ruby 2.7.3` version by following command

```
ruby --version
```

then run your server using

```
rails s
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question.